# Parent of HTML div in GWT

Tags: html, gwt, iframe

I am adding an iFrame with a source URL to a container panel that is provided to me and the HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="Unknown">
    <iframe src='...'> / /this is the iframe I added
        <html> 
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <div id="IHaveAccess"/> // this is the div I have access to
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

My question is: I have access to the com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element corresponding to the div with id "IHaveAccess". Is there a way I can get access to the div with id "Unknown".

I tried to browse up the hierarchy (element.GetParentElement()) all the way to the element corresponding to the html tag, but the parent element of that html tag is always null, even  when the iFrame has been attached. Is there a way to go above the inner html tag.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried Document.get().getElementById()?

Comment: Or else why not search for container element's child?